# Upgrade Windows Server non-english in Azure

Tags: azure, windows-server-2016, windows-server-2022

I am migrating a VM with WS 2016 Standard to Azure, and in the test migration I selected the upgrade to WS 2022, and it has given this error "compatscan failed with the error code -1047526908" about which I cannot find more information...

I am also trying to perform the manual update, but the image that is downloaded is the English version and the migrated version is in Spanish.
This is the official documentation from Microsoft:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows-in-place-upgrade

Thanks and regards

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately -1047526908 is `error 0xc1900204` which apparently is "update failed" with little other explanation. One thing that I've found extremely useful in cases like this is to use the Programmer view of the Windows calculator to convert the decimal error code into a DWORD hex code; searching on the hex value quite often results in much better results from searches.  Perhaps  try searching the Web with the hex version of the error code `C1900204`; there are a lot of different things that might help, far too many for here.